# Passing parameter from Runbook Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to Powershell on VM

Tags: azure, powershell, power-automate, azure-runbook

I'm trying to execute the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand in PowerShell and pass parameters to the script that needs to be executed.

Before I Run the Runbook I can define the parameter name:
[Define Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWXmE.png)

Code from the Runbook:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$name
)



Write-Output "Connecting to azure via Connect-AzAccount -Identity"
Connect-AzAccount -Identity 
Write-Output "Successfully connected with Automation account's Managed Identity"

Write-Output "Run Script Against Machines"


$ScriptToRun = "C:\testps.ps1"

Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1 

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "RG" `
                      -VMName "VM" `
                      -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' `
                      -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1 `
                      -Parameter @{"name" = $name}
                    
Remove-Item -Path ScriptToRun.ps1
```

Script on the server I want to execute with the parameters:

```
param(
    [string]$name
)

MKdir -Path "C:\Users" -Name $name
```

The script does not produce the expected output: Creating a folder with name from the parametr under C:\Users. No folder is being created.

If I execute the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand on the same script with hardcoded arguments like so:

MKdir -Path "C:\Users" -Name "TEST"
it does work and the folder gets created.

Comment: You cannot create a folder c:\Users unless you are an admin.  Try a different folder location

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. When I execute the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand on the same script with hardcoded arguments like so:

MKdir -Path "C:\Users" -Name "TEST" 

it does work and the folder gets created. So I dont think its a permission issue.

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the folder?  Can you manually add a file to the folder?

Comment: Yes I can manually create a file in the folder.

Comment: Change `-Parameter @{"name" = $name}` to `-Parameter @{name = $name}`; do you get the same issue?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood Yes unfortanetly I have the same issue

Comment: Your script to run is just a ps1 file containing a file path; have you confirmed if you do `.\ScriptToRun.ps1` on your local system it works? It doesn't look to me like the script you're actually passing to Invoke-AzVMRunCommand has any parameters itself. Why can't you pass the actual script to Invoke-AzVMRunCommand, why are you wrapping it in another ps1 file?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood Yes when I run the Script on the VM without the parameters it creates the folder. I have to wrap it in another file because else it wont find the file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796082/could-not-find-file-invoke-azurermvmruncommand

Comment: $ScriptToRun doesn't have a param block; it should be `$ScriptToRun = "C:\testps.ps1 -name $name"` and remove parameter from `Invoke-AzVmRunCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have script on VM and i have followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest):

```php
param(
    [string]$name
)
MKdir -Path "C:\Users" -Name $name
```

Then i have used  az invoke command in your script instead of `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` and used below command:

```py
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name "name of the VM" -g "name of the resourcegrp" --scripts "C:\test.ps1  $name"
```

Here $name is the param that you have send to runbook.

By this way you can create the folder with the name you want.

**References taken from:**

- [Executing Powershell script on Remote VM on Azure with Parameters - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326154/executing-powershell-script-on-remote-vm-on-azure-with-parameters/75331629#75331629)
- [How to pass json file as parameter to Azure Powershell Runbook? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74703049/how-to-pass-json-file-as-parameter-to-azure-powershell-runbook/74712739#74712739)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The "az vm run-command" unfortanetly doesnt work in the Runbook. It is not recognized. As this is Powershell I think I need to use Invoke-AzVMRunCommand https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell

Comment: Have you got any informtion from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74703049/how-to-pass-json-file-as-parameter-to-azure-powershell-runbook/74712739#74712739 reference

Comment: No I dont think this helps. I can get the parameter from Powerapps to the Runbook. But not from the Runbook to the PS Script on the VM.

Comment: Without them I doesnt work. And also the Command works when I try to excecute the Script on the VM without parameters.

Comment: Using Powershell I have tried too, I am getting Blank Parameters as you have got.